# Como acceder al form.cleaned_data un campo de un formulario cuyo atributo utiliza unas choices proveidas en el modelo

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Estoy usando Django. Tengo un atributo en un modelo que utiliza una Tupla de choices, eso llega al template como un select y todo ok, el problema esta cuando envío el formulario por POST al view, e intento acceder a `form.cleaned_data['atributo']`, me dice que ese arreglo no tiene ese atributo, y es cierto, pero mi pregunta es de que forma puedo acceder a ese atributo.

```
#Modelo

    class Tribunal(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    fecha = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, default= datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    presidente = models.ForeignKey(Profesor, models.CASCADE,related_name='presidente', db_column='presidente')
    secretario = models.ForeignKey(Profesor, models.CASCADE,related_name='secretario', db_column='secretario')
    vocal = models.ForeignKey(Profesor, models.CASCADE, db_column='vocal')
    suplente = models.ForeignKey(Profesor, models.CASCADE,related_name='suplente', db_column='suplente', blank=True, null=True)
    lugar = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    SESSIONS = ((1,'Mañana'),(2,'Tarde'))
    sesion = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True,verbose_name="Sesión", choices= SESSIONS)
    aprobado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    convocatoria = models.ForeignKey(Convocatoria, models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tribunal'
# Form
class TribunalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_presidente(self):
        perfil_tecnico = models.NmPerfilProfesor.objects.get(id=1)
        presidente = self.cleaned_data['presidente']
        tribunals_this_session = models.Tribunal.objects.get(sesion=int(self.cleaned_data['sesion']))
        for t in tribunals_this_session:
            if presidente in t.miembros:
                raise ValidationError('Error al escoger el presidente')

    class Meta:
        model = models.Tribunal
        fields = ['presidente', 'secretario', 'vocal', 'suplente', 'convocatoria', 'nombre', 'fecha', 'lugar', 'sesion']
        widgets = {
            "presidente": widgets.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "secretario": widgets.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "vocal": widgets.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "suplente": widgets.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "convocatoria": widgets.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "sesion": widgets.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "lugar": widgets.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "nombre": widgets.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            "fecha": DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'min': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}),
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu formulario es un `ModelForm`, está vinculado a un modelo. Hay un [método extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) que cubre la necesidad:  `get_FOO_display()` donde FOO es el nombre del campo.

En tu caso la solución és `form.get_sesion_display()`

Si el Form no se basa en un `ModelForm`, por lo tanto el formulario no es instanciable con un modelo, la solución es otra:

```
sesion = form.cleaned_data['sesion']
sesion_display = dict(form.fields['sesion'].choices)[sesion]
```

Esta también te sirve, pero es mas `pythonica` la primera, en tu caso.

#### testeo

He simplificado tus models y form para ejemplificar:

```
#models.py
class Tribunal(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    lugar = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    SESSIONS = ((1, 'Mañana'), (2, 'Tarde'))
    sesion = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Sesión", choices=SESSIONS)
    aprobado = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'tribunal'
```

```
#form.py
class TribunalForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean_presidente(self):

        presidente = self.cleaned_data['presidente']

    class Meta:
        model = Tribunal
        fields = ['nombre', 'aprobado', 'lugar', 'sesion']
```

verificación:

```
form = TribunalForm({'nombre':'hola','aprovado':True,'lugar': 'Hola','sesion':1})
form.is_valid()
>>>True

form.cleaned_data
>>>{'nombre': 'hola', 'aprobado': False, 'lugar': 'Hola', 'sesion': 1}

form.cleaned_data['sesion']
>>>1

form.fields['sesion']
>>><django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0x7fbf0a57db50>

form.fields['sesion'].choices
>>>[('', '---------'), (1, 'Mañana'), (2, 'Tarde')]

form.instance.get_sesion_display()
>>>'Mañana'

form = TribunalForm({'nombre':'hola','aprovado':True,'lugar': 'Hola','sesion':2})
form.instance.get_sesion_display()
>>>'Tarde'
```